# Need to build a report in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me:

1. consolidate a bunch of queries that I have that work into something cleaner than 17 separate queries; and
2. understand *how* to merge queries like this?

The biggest problem I have is crossing tables.

These are the queries I have:

```
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from account      WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from call         WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from campaign     WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from case         WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from lead         WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from meeting      WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from opportunity  WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;
SELECT Created_by_id,count(*) as Total from task         WHERE created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by Created_by_id;

SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from account     WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from call        WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from campaign    WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from case        WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from lead        WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from meeting     WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from opportunity WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
SELECT modified_by_id,count(*) as Total from task        WHERE modified_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' group by modified_by_id;
```

They work just fine. I run each one, copy the results into a spreadsheet (row by row, sorting by ID). Next I go into *another* table (user) and just copy the contents of that table into the same spreadsheet. Each ID from `modified_by_id` and `created_by_id` lines up with a username. Then I can delete the "id" column and I have a report to give to managers.

I just want to streamline all this into a single query where I only have to change the date range and go... But more importantly, I want to understand *how* to do it and how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm tempted to agree with BK on this one

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't even know where to begin. Like I said, the current process takes hours because I have to run each query, copy the output to a file, then merge the results in a spreadsheet. Simple enough to do, but extremely tedious.

Answer (score 1):

I have 30 years of experience with SQL. I have written [a book on SQL](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns/).

I would not try to make those queries into one query.

Because they come from different tables, and they group by different columns, there is no way to make those queries into one query, except technically as a UNION of a bunch of individual queries.

Running the queries individually is the better choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know two things.

Sub Query, Union All

Lets say we created two table

```
create table a(a_id integer, a_name char(20));
create table b(b_id integer, b_name char(20));
```

and have some data inside it

```
insert into a(a_id, a_name) values(1, "a");
insert into b(b_id, b_name) values(1, "b");
```

we can make a union all query to combine two similar table

```
(select a_id as id, a_name as name  from a) union all (select b_id as id, b_name as name  from b)
```

Result is

```
id  name
1   a
1   b
```

Now lets make this subquery to be source or another query

```
select new_tab.id as id, count(new_tab.name) as count from  ( 
    (select a_id as id, a_name as name  from a) union all (select b_id as id, b_name as name  from b) 
) as new_tab 
group by new_tab.id;
```

Result is:

```
id  count
1   2
```

Hope this helps to figure out how to make a single query for your case.